# How can i get and use AspnetUsers UserId in migration configuration file?

Tags: entity-framework, configuration, database-migration, entity-framework-migrations, asp.net-identity

This is the code of configuration file(seed method) of entity framework migration. 
Through this code, i create a user and role for AspnetUsers table and i put the user in role named Admin.

```
AppUserManager userMgr = new AppUserManager(new UserStore<AppUser>(context));
        AppRoleManager roleMgr = new AppRoleManager(new RoleStore<AppRole>(context));
        string roleName = "Admin";
        string userName = "admin@educationboard.com";
        string password = "Sifre";
        string email = "admin@educationboard.com";
        if (!roleMgr.RoleExists(roleName))
        {
            roleMgr.Create(new AppRole(roleName));
        }
        AppUser user = userMgr.FindByName(userName);
        if (user == null)
        {
            userMgr.Create(new AppUser { UserName = userName, Email = email },
            password);
            user = userMgr.FindByName(userName);
        }
        if (!userMgr.IsInRole(user.Id, roleName))
        {
            userMgr.AddToRole(user.Id, roleName);
        }
        foreach (AppUser dbUser in userMgr.Users)
        {
            dbUser.Cinsiyet = eCinsiyetler.Erkek;
        }
        context.SaveChanges();
```

Then i also create an entity named Articles, each article has an author id. I named AuthorId as UserId in Article entity. How can i get and use UserId I've just created above  in following code?

```
var articles= new List<Article>
        {
            new Article{Title="Title 1", AddedDate=DateTime.Now,  Content="content here.",  UserId=.(What code should be here? }; 
articles.ForEach(p => context.Articles.AddOrUpdate(s => s.Title, p));
        context.SaveChanges();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why can't you query for the user like you did above?

```
AppUser user = userMgr.FindByName(userName);
        if (user == null)
        {
            userMgr.Create(new AppUser { UserName = userName, Email = email },
            password);
            user = userMgr.FindByName(userName);
        }
```

and then have user.Id?

If you have a handle in ApplicationDbContext you could easily do something like

```
ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();
var user = db.AspNetUser.Single(x => x.UserName == username);
var id = user.Id;
```